# Robotium AssertionFailedError: View with id: '2131230724' is not found

Tags: java, android, robotium

My Robotium testcase is not clicking the button, and it exits with the following error:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: View with id: '2131230724' is not found!

Part of Testcase:

```
            if (!(solo.searchText(section))) {

            solo.goBack();
            //solo.clickOnText("Download Section");
            solo.clickOnView((Button) solo.getView(R.id.btnDownloadData));
            solo.enterText((EditText) solo.getView(R.id.edUsername), institute);
            solo.enterText((EditText) solo.getView(R.id.edPassword), institute_pass);
            solo.clickOnView((Button) solo.getView(R.id.btnLogin));
            solo.clickOnText(section);
            //solo.sleep(10000);
            solo.waitForDialogToClose();
            solo.clickOnView((Button) solo.getView(R.id.btnSelectLocalDB));
        }
```

But the same testcase worked the first time, later it started failing with an error.
Even tried uninstalling APK before running the testcase, but the same results.